# Airplane vector problem - wind due east, plane northeast; need help drawing a picture

Tags: calculus, vectors

A wind is blowing straight east with a velocity of 25 mph and an aircraft is flying pointed North East (.e., at a $45^{\circ}$ if the $y$-axis points north and the $x$-axis points east) and records an airspeed of $130$ mph.

I need to determine in which direction and how fast the airplane is actually traveling.

Numerically, I can figure this out, but I am having difficulty imagining what this looks like as a picture. The only examples I've done thus far are ones where the wind was pointing either due north or at an angle smaller than $90^{\circ}$, and so I'm having trouble drawing a picture of the scenario - I'm not sure how the wind should displace the path of the airplane. Could somebody please draw me a picture? That's really all I need here to figure out the rest on my own.

Thanks.

Comment: Taking, as usual, "north" upward, "east" to the right, etc.  Draw a line from the center of your paper to the right.  Using whatever units you like, measure off a distance of "25 mph" (if 1/8 inch represents 1 mph, it would be 25/8= 3 and 1/8 inch).   From the tip of that vector, draw a second line at 45 degrees and measure "130" mph (130/8= 16 and 1/4 inches).  The actual path of the aircraft is the third side of that triangle and its ground speed is the length of that side.

Comment: @user247327 got it. But then how do I find the angle that the resultant vector makes with the x-axis?

Comment: You a triangle in which you know the "lengths" of two sides (25 and 140) and the angle between them(135 degrees). you can use the "cosine law", $c^2= a^2+ b^2- 2ab cos(C)$., to find the  length of the third side, C.  You an then use the "sine law", $\frac{sin(A)}{a}= \frac{sin(B)}{b}= \frac{sin(C)}{c}$ to find the other two angles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the diagram below:

[image: airplane_velocity_in_wind_diagram]

The vector with length $130~\text{mph}$ at an angle of $45^\circ$ north of east represents the trajectory of the airplane in the absence of wind.  The vector with magnitude $25~\text{mph}$ in the easterly direction represents the velocity of the wind.  The vector $v$ represents the resultant velocity of the airplane.

Comment: thank you so much! I have just one more little favor - I was able to figure out that $v=\langle 65\sqrt{2}+25, 65\sqrt{2}\rangle$ and so has a magnitude of approximately $148.73$ mph. Can you help me find the value of the angle $\theta$?

Comment: Draw an altitude from the tip of $v$ to the eastward vector.  Observe that $$\tan\theta = \frac{65\sqrt{2}}{65\sqrt{2} + 25}$$